# Connecting PySpark from a docker container to a local machine's hive table

Tags: docker, hive, pyspark

I have built a decision tree model using Pyspark and I want to deploy that model using the docker container. I am using spark 1.6.0. The data is stored in the Hive tables and is located in my local machine. Is there a way to connect PySpark from my docker container to the hive tables in my local machine?

The data in my hive tables might get updated so I don't want to mount a drive or just copy the folder from local to my container but establish a connection between PySpark and Hive tables.

Answer (score 0):

If the data lives locally, you can still run Hive in a docker container, and mount the local folder inside the Hive container.

With `docker-compose` you can then easily link the containers and access the Hive server through `localhost`

Another option is to use `--network="host"` when running you PySpark container, and it will network through the host network.
Might not be what you want for security reasons, depending on what you do.

see [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried with --network="host" but still I cannot access local Hadoop files. I can ping from the container to local but cannot access files.

Comment: and from local to Hive you can access the files? if not, it's not a docker issue. if you can, then it may be a permission issue with the user inside the container.